# Why isn't my logo appearing on my partial page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have made a application and the logo appears on every page.  All 3 of my layouts are copy and pasted to be identical. I have 2 partials linking to 2 pages in the same view folder and the logo works with one and doesn't with the other.  It just displays the "alt" name of the `<img>`.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest -and I apologise for this- that the obvious answer is that you're not correctly calling the image file.

Check the URI of the image -in the generated (x)html- to make sure that, in the finished page, it's pointing to the correct file. My own issues in these situations tend to be deleting a period (`../image.png` becomes `./image.png`), a typo on the file type (`image.png' as`image.pgp` -I don't know why) or some other typo-based issue.

I'm sorry I can't be more technical but those are, in my experience, the most common answers.

Comment: Let's say you have /products/1/view and /products/list as end points, and you have your image in /images/logo.png. If you use the relative location on your template i.e. ../images/logo.png, it will work for /products/list but not for /products/1/view. You should use absolute path like /images/logo.png on both templates.

Comment: Isn't your final example a root-relative path, not an absolute path (my understanding is an *absolute* path is of the form "protocol://subdomain.domain-name.tld/directory/file.extension")?

Comment: Thanks you Igor it worked perfectly when I deleted the .. on the paths in the templates. Just the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to accept the answer, then... =p Unless it was @Igor, in which case it'd be only fair to ask him to post his comment as an answer and accept that.